# Jenkins jobs hanging while copying the config files to slave

Tags: jenkins

I am facing a problme where my Jenkins job hangs while copying the maven config files to slave machines as below:

```
Starting build...
[Pipeline] configFileProvider
provisioning config files...
copy managed file [IDS Maven Settings for ECDP Nexus With Credentials Provided (IDS Build User)] to file:/u01/apps/jenkins/workspace/cations_ps.smoke_hotfix_8.20.2@tmp/config3733643605127657054tmp

After this the status cog keeps on spinning and be like that for hours untill I manually interrrupt either to disconnect and reconnect the slave or restart the Master itself.

I am not getting anything in the logs as logs are not progressed any more to tell what is causing this issue. I even tried to give more memory to master Jenkins JVM by increasing the Xmx value as it might get exhausted while running n number of jobs simultaneously. 

I took few dumps from Jenkins and sharing below the dumps from hanging slave for more insight.

"AsyncAppender-asyncOctaneFileAppender" Id=1255 Group=main WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@299e00e4,   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@299e00e4,   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175),   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039),   at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403),   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender$AsyncThread.run(AsyncAppender.java:403), , Blocking to write '.com..common.ui.validator.SearchManifestValidatorTest</className>' 0x0a ' <testName>testInvalidDateRangeNullEndDate</testName>' 0x0a ' <skipped>false</skipped>' 0x0a ' <failedSince>0</failedSince>' 0x0a ' </case>' 0x0a ' </cases>' 0x0a ' </suit': pool-1-thread-2155 : IO ID=1085 : seq#=1084, "Blocking to write '.com..common.ui.validator.SearchManifestValidatorTest</className>' 0x0a, '          <testName>testInvalidDateRangeNullEndDate</testName>' 0x0a, '          <skipped>false</skipped>' 0x0a, '          <failedSince>0</failedSince>' 0x0a, '        </case>' 0x0a, '      </cases>' 0x0a, '    </suit': pool-1-thread-2155 : IO ID=1085 : seq#=1084" Id=2261 Group=main TIMED_WAITING on [B@68a30adf,  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method),    -  waiting on [B@68a30adf,  at hudson.remoting.FastPipedOutputStream.write(FastPipedOutputStream.java:171),     at hudson.remoting.FastPipedOutputStream.write(FastPipedOutputStream.java:138),     at hudson.remoting.ProxyOutputStream$Chunk$1.run(ProxyOutputStream.java:255),   at hudson.remoting.PipeWriter$1.run(PipeWriter.java:158),   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511),     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266),    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131),     at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72),     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266),    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), ,     Number of locked synchronizers = 1,     - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@4c395a75, , Channel reader thread: channel, "Channel reader thread: channel" Id=11 Group=main RUNNABLE (in native),    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method),    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255),  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246),  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265),  -  locked java.io.BufferedInputStream@26c0fea3,     at hudson.remoting.FlightRecorderInputStream.read(FlightRecorderInputStream.java:91),   at hudson.remoting.ChunkedInputStream.readHeader(ChunkedInputStream.java:72),   at hudson.remoting.ChunkedInputStream.readUntilBreak(ChunkedInputStream.java:103),  at hudson.remoting.ChunkedCommandTransport.readBlock(ChunkedCommandTransport.java:39),  at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34),     at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:63), , jenkins.util.Timer [#10], "jenkins.util.Timer [#10]" Id=1202 Group=main WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175),   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809),    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , jenkins.util.Timer [#1], "jenkins.util.Timer [#1]" Id=1179 Group=main WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175),   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809),    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , jenkins.util.Timer [#2], "jenkins.util.Timer [#2]" Id=1180 Group=main WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175),   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809),    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , jenkins.util.Timer [#3], "jenkins.util.Timer [#3]" Id=1181 Group=main WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175),   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809),    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , jenkins.util.Timer [#4], "jenkins.util.Timer [#4]" Id=1185 Group=main WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175),   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809),    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , jenkins.util.Timer [#5], "jenkins.util.Timer [#5]" Id=1186 Group=main WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175),   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809),    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , jenkins.util.Timer [#6], "jenkins.util.Timer [#6]" Id=1187 Group=main WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175),   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809),    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , jenkins.util.Timer [#7], "jenkins.util.Timer [#7]" Id=1188 Group=main TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215),  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078),  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809),    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , jenkins.util.Timer [#8], "jenkins.util.Timer [#8]" Id=1200 Group=main WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175),   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809),    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , jenkins.util.Timer [#9], "jenkins.util.Timer [#9]" Id=1201 Group=main WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10714461,   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175),   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809),    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , JGit-WorkQueue, "JGit-WorkQueue" Id=1227 Group=main TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@187d4876,    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@187d4876,   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215),  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078),  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809),    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , Log4j2-TF-2-Scheduled-1, "Log4j2-TF-2-Scheduled-1" Id=1254 Group=main TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@68785254,  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@68785254,   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215),  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078),  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093),   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809),    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , main, "main" Id=1 Group=main TIMED_WAITING on hudson.remoting.Channel@28ba21f3,     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method),    -  waiting on hudson.remoting.Channel@28ba21f3,     at hudson.remoting.Channel.join(Channel.java:1135),     at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:796),    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.runWithStdinStdout(Launcher.java:718),  at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:398),     at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:298), , Ping thread for channel hudson.remoting.Channel@28ba21f3:channel, "Ping thread for channel hudson.remoting.Channel@28ba21f3:channel" Id=16 Group=main TIMED_WAITING,     at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method),   at hudson.remoting.PingThread.run(PingThread.java:94), , pool-1-thread-2149 for channel id=346601, "pool-1-thread-2149 for channel id=346601" Id=2242 Group=main WAITING on java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@6c9c9313,   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@6c9c9313,     at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175),   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:429),  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191),    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:367),     at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72),     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266),    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), ,     Number of locked synchronizers = 1,     - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@5d97fedf, , pool-1-thread-2164, "pool-1-thread-2164" Id=2319 Group=main RUNNABLE,  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215),  at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460),     at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362),     at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , pool-1-thread-2166, "pool-1-thread-2166" Id=2321 Group=main TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@7ec77a95,  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@7ec77a95,     at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215),  at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460),     at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362),     at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , pool-1-thread-2168 for channel id=347501, "pool-1-thread-2168 for channel id=347501" Id=2323 Group=main RUNNABLE,   at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpThreads0(Native Method),   at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpAllThreads(ThreadImpl.java:446),   at hudson.Functions.getThreadInfos(Functions.java:1303),    at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$GetThreadDump.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:98),     at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$GetThreadDump.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:95),     at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211),   at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54),    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369),     at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72),     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266),    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), ,     Number of locked synchronizers = 1,     - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@98f6f51, , pool-1-thread-2169, "pool-1-thread-2169" Id=2324 Group=main TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@7ec77a95,  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@7ec77a95,     at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215),  at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460),     at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362),     at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , pool-1-thread-2170, "pool-1-thread-2170" Id=2325 Group=main TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@7ec77a95,  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),     -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@7ec77a95,     at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215),  at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460),     at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362),     at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066),   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127),     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , RemoteInvocationHandler [#30], "RemoteInvocationHandler [#30]" Id=2289 Group=main TIMED_WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@29c16a52,  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method),    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@29c16a52,   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143),    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$Unexporter.run(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:600),    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511),     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266),    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:111),    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745), , Finalizer, "Finalizer" Id=3 Group=system WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@6e2099e5,     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method),    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@6e2099e5,   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143),    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164),    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209), , Reference Handler, "Reference Handler" Id=2 Group=system WAITING on java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock@2bf64566,    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method),    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock@2bf64566,    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502),  at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157), , Signal Dispatcher, "Signal Dispatcher": non-Java thread
    <empty stack>
```